# std::atomic<bool> and lambda

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, atomic, stdasync

Does anybody know why this program goes into an infinite loop, instead of stopping after 5s or so?

This happens with both the latest gcc and clang compiler; does `atomic_bool` suffer from hte same issues as a vector of `bool`?

If I use `atomic<int>` this works fine.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <future>
#include <chrono>


using namespace std;
using namespace chrono_literals;

void send_heart_beat()
{
    cout << "sending heartbeat" << endl;
}

std::future<void> f;
int main()
{
   std::atomic<bool> stop(false);
   f = std::async(std::launch::async,[&stop]() { while(!stop) { send_heart_beat(); std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s); } });
   std::this_thread::sleep_for(5s);
   stop = true;
}
```

Comment: Once main exits, stop ceases to exist. Any attempt to access it is UB.

Comment: Your program exhibits undefined behavior, by way of access through a dangling reference. `stop` goes out of scope and is destroyed while the lambda is still running and checking it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 std::atomic<bool> stop(false);
 std::future<void> f;
```

These two variables are in different scopes, and `f`'s scope is longer lived than `stop`'s scope.

```
f = std::async(std::launch::async,[&stop]() { while(!stop) { send_heart_beat(); std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s); } });
```

here we bind a reference to `stop` into a lambda, and then store a (copy) of that lambda into an `async` object which is managed by `f`.

When `f` goes out of scope, its destructor waits for the async task to finish.  But because `f`'s scope is longer lasting than `stop`'s, we leave the scope of `stop` before `f` waits for the thread to finish.

So our thread mindlessly continues accessing `stop` after `stop` no longer exists through a dangling reference.

This results in undefined behavior; any behavior by your program is acceptable to the standard.